# return from function changes value of array element in c

Tags: arrays, c, return-value

I am trying to implement a function which fills a struct, including an `int array[3][31]`. Inside the function everything is fine but when I return a pointer to my struct and print it out in the main function the elements [1][0] and [2][0], which should both be 0, are 32 and 4.

I already went over it with the debugger but the values just change as soon as it leaves the function.

Here are the relevant parts of my function:

```
struct monat* create_monat(int zahl_tage, int erster_tag){
    int wochen_tage[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    monat* neuer_monat = malloc(sizeof(monat));
    int count =0;
    while(neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] !=2){
        int wochen_tag = wochen_tage[(erster_tag-1 +count) %7];

        neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] = count+1;

        neuer_monat->kalender[1][count] = wochen_tag;

        if((wochen_tag == 7) || (wochen_tag == 6)){
            neuer_monat->kalender[2][count] =1;
        }
        else{
            neuer_monat->kalender[2][count] =0;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return neuer_monat;
}
```

And I am calling it with this

```
int main(){

    monat* jan24 = create_monat(31, 1);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int u=0; u<31; u++){
            printf("%.2d ", jan24->kalender[i][u]);
        }
        printf("\n");
```

Can somebody help please?

Comment: `while(neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] !=2)` - `neuer_monat` is unitialized, so why do you expect any value out of it?

Comment: You can use `calloc` to initialise the memory block to `0`, assuming that `kalender` is a fixed array and not an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: Odd that you would have a `wochen_tage` array that simply maps [0-6] to [1-7]. Just use day index + 1.

Comment: Hint: Don't write code in your own language (german it seems). Write code in english so that it's easy to share. E.g. `create_monat` --> `create_month`

Comment: Also you need to show us the definiton of `struct monat`

Comment: And show us the code that prints the values inside the function.

Comment: ... or get used to the typical 0-based numbering, as used in `struct tm.tm_wday` and adjust at the user interface.

Comment: I would like to help but you didnt show the definition of the monat structure. Or is it just a structure with `int kalender[3][31];`? Still, you should post a working code so its easier to help you.

Comment: @FelixK You need to provided the requested information. Otherwise your question can't be answered and we'll have to close it.

Comment: OK, I dont know if I should put this as a answer but the problem is that when you iterate the array in the line `neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] = count + 1;`, or any line that uses `[count]`, at some point you try to access the element ...[...][31], and I think you know that there is no 31th element in your matrix (in a matrix[31] the first element is 0 and the last is 30, the size -1), so when you try to access the element [0][31] you are actually acessing [1][0].

Comment: Closest solution was changing the condition on while, which you should use a for, from != 2 to != 1. The only thing is that [1][0] Shows 1, and you said in the question that it was suposed to be 0, which personally doesnt make sense cause from what I undertood it was suposed to be days of the week, so 1 makes sense. The only thing I would say is that this code looks way to complex for such a simple thing.

Comment: Is a `monat` the same thing as a `struct monat`?  If so, then choose *one* type name and use it consistently.  Perferably `struct monat`.  But if they are different then for goodness's sake, rename one of them.

Comment: @EnderMega thank you very much you were wrigth it works know

Answer (score 0):

Use `neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] != 1` and not `neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] != 2`.

I also changed so it uses a for loop.

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct monat {

    int kalender[3][31];
};

monat* create_monat(int zahl_tage, int erster_tag)
{
    int wochen_tage[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    monat* neuer_monat = (monat*)malloc(sizeof(monat));
    if (!neuer_monat)
        return 0;

    for (int count = 0; neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] != 1; count++)
    {
        int wochen_tag = wochen_tage[(erster_tag - 1 + count) % 7];

        neuer_monat->kalender[0][count] = count + 1;

        neuer_monat->kalender[1][count] = wochen_tag;

        if ((wochen_tag == 7) || (wochen_tag == 6))
            neuer_monat->kalender[2][count] = 1;
        else
            neuer_monat->kalender[2][count] = 0;
    }

    return neuer_monat;
}

int main()
{
    monat* jan24 = create_monat(31, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < 31; u++)
        {
            printf("%.2d ", jan24->kalender[i][u]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```